# subscribe and unsubscribe to topic - firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a website in HTML, JS, and CSS. My result is a PWA (Progressive Web App). It works really great. I am hosting and serving it via the Firebase Hosting and enjoy many functions of firebase. To let the user feel the full power of a PWA I need to manage Push Notifications. For that, I want to use Firebase Cloud Messaging. I already know how to send push notifications and so on. On my webpage, the users can subscribe to topics. And here we go. I do not know how to subscribe/unsubscribe a user to a topic via the javascript without the admins SDK. Can please provide somebody a clear and simple example for subscribe/unsubscribe users? From the documentation, I will not be smart.

Thanks in advance,
Filip.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like that:

(I assume you have users tokens stored somwhere in the database ordered by users id)

Create table 'topics' - store users ids there.

Create form - let the user add its id to the 'topic' table.

Then, before sending FCM, store every token, from owners which ids are assigned to the specific topic in the 'topic' table.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your very helpful answer. I coded it just right now. Now I only have to tasks I have to do. Receiving and sending messages via javascript. I followed this link: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging But 1) I do not know how to send push notifications to a list of tokens and 2) can you please explain me what code I must write that users get a push notification. Because I added the firebase-messaging-sw.js and followed the instructions in setting up messaging, but can't receive any messages.